# Website Contact Form and Google Workspace

Tags: php, contact-form, google-workspace, spf

Before I post this question, I checked similar posts and any answer helped me to solve this problem, so, here's what happens:

We have a simple php contact form in our website that sends emails [with the php mail() function], but since we moved to GWorkspace the contact form now just sends emails to any email account but ours. In other words: any-user@gmail.com get the email and any-user@mydomain.com does not get the email.

I also tried to send email with phpmailer via smtp and same happen as mentioned above.

According to GWorkspace documentation (https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en):

If you send mail in one or more of these ways in addition to Google Workspace, you must create a custom TXT record for SPF:

```
You send mail from other servers.
You use a third-party mail provider.
Your website uses a service that generates automatic emails, for example you have a "Contact us" form.
```

So I create the custom TXT record for SPF with the following contents:

v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all

Did that but the contact form still not working. I was wondering if I have missed any extra step.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your domain's SPF config and permitted destinations using [Scott Kitterman's validator](https://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your website host to the spf record.

Your hosting platform should be able to advise of the correct spf for their platform and then you can combine this with the Google one into a single record.

Typically it will look somthing like:

`v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.google.com include:spf.hostingprovider.com ~all`

The `a` and `mx` flags are not required by Google but may be needed for your hosting provider.